# How to sort by _doc using elasticsearch java client

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to iterate on entire elasticsearch index/type. I am using scroll in java client as below

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(test)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setQuery(qb)
        .setSize(100).execute().actionGet();
```

As suggested in docs in the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-scroll.html).

"Scroll requests have optimizations that make them faster when the sort order is _doc. If you want to iterate over all documents regardless of the order, this is the most efficient option"

```
"sort": [
    "_doc"
  ]
```

How to set sort order to "_doc" in java client code above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this :

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = elasticsearchTemplate.client.prepareSearch(test)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
            .setQuery(qb).addSort("_doc" , SortOrder.ASC)
            .setSize(100).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Accepted :). Didn't know about this button earlier. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for your info -There are two buttons. One to vote up and other to accept the answer. Vote up can be done by anyone. Accept is done by the one who asked the question